# Display contacts in Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I had retrieved the contacts from the phone book and displayed the contacts in pop up of Blackberry Simulator. It runs well in simulator, but not running in Blackberry Device. I stuck on this. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Application Permissions?

Comment: Actually I am a newbie. Its working in simulator but not in device. So can you please help me?

Comment: We're gonna need more to go on than that.  What error message is it giving you?  What behavior are you seeing right now?  Show us some relevant sections of your code.

Comment: In your device, go to options-> Applications, look for your app, push menu -> edit permissions, set the permissions to allow and try again. If it works, you can modify the code to request the permission for reading contacts programmatically on application start.

Comment: I think Rafael is likely correct, but another difference is the content inside the contacts. Check you're not getting any null pointers etc where you expect a name and there isn't one... either way please help yourself by providing the info Jonathan asked for in this and future questions

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between simulator environment and actual device environment: **permissions**

On simulator you can access any device resources/data without setting relevant permissions. But on actual devices you need the relevant permissions set, before accessing device resources.

Use [ApplicationPermissionsManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html) and [ApplicationPermissions](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html) classes to invoke "Permissions request" screen on your app startup.

You need at least [ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_ORGANIZER_DATA](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html#PERMISSION_ORGANIZER_DATA) permission allowed for your application.